# 2.80 - Coordinates of child show as global

Tags: objects

I can't find any solution to this problem online. It seems like everyone says children position should be displayed relative to parent. This is what I need.

Here's an example with cubes. Parent cube (bottom) is at 4,0,0. Left is at 2,0,0, Right is at 6,0,0. How do I make transform coords to display relative to parent (left -2,0,0; right 2,0,0)?

This is the most recent 2.80 build. I had same issue in some early April build.

[image: cubes]

Comment: I should add that if I grab parent cube and move it somewhere else, the child cubes still display 2,0,0 and 6,0,0, despite the fact that they're not at these global locations and not at these parent relative locations.

Comment: How did you create child cubes? Did you move them after parenting? What location were they located at when parented?

Comment: Try alt-p clear parent inverse.